# How To Use Pretty Photo in Mobile apps

Tags: jquery, html, windows-phone-7, cordova, prettyphoto

I'm Developing Windows Phone App Using Phone gap.

I want To Use Pretty Mobile jquery In to Project.

Pretty Mobile Jquery Website: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettymobile/

I just Copied And Change the File Location Correctly But Out Put Is Empty It's Show Only White Color.

In the Above URL Also Not Working It show A Pretty Mobile Only . Any One Tell Me How To Use Pretty Mobile In Windows Phone 7 App .

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>prettyMobile</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="white" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyMobile.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/native-iphone.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="js/sizzle.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/prettyMobile.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>  
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 100);" onorientationchange="updateOrientation();">
    <div id="pm_container">
        <div id="pm_header">
            <h1 class="pm_page-title">prettyMobile</h1>
            <p class="pm_back"><a href="#" rel="back"><strong>Back</strong></a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="pm_in-viewport">

        </div>
        <div class="pm_out-of-viewport"></div>
        <div id="pm_loader"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any One Plz Tell Me How To Make It Work...

Other Wise Tell Any Alternative Way To Do Same Functionality Like Pretty Photo

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
        *[class~=pp_pic_holder] { width: 100% !important; left: 0px !important; }  
        *[class~=pp_hoverContainer] { width: 90% !important; height: 180px !important;  }  
        *[class~=pp_fade] { width: 389px !important;  } 
        *[class~=pp_hoverContainer] { height: 190px !important;  }   
        *[class~=pp_right] { height: 220px !important;  }   
        *[class~=pp_content]  { height: 100% !important; width: 320px !important; }  
        #fullResImage { height: 100% !important; width: 320px !important; }  

}
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Comment: The star selectors as they are are completely unnecessary.